# finding events via reflection c#

Tags: c#, events, reflection, fieldinfo

I have a problem concerning Events and Reflection in C#.
I'm currently programming with the Microsoft Kinect (SDK 1.7) and want to implement a different click than the "Push-To-Press"-Approach. The ClickEvent itself is declared in the KinectControl class.

```
    public partial class KinectControl : UserControl
    {
        /**
        \brief Default Click event 
        */

        public static readonly RoutedEvent ClickEvent =
            EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Click", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(KinectControl)); 
        [...]

        public event RoutedEventHandler Click
        {
            add
            {
                AddHandler(ClickEvent, value);
            }
            remove
            {
                RemoveHandler(ClickEvent, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

The Control which should raise this ClickEvent and invoke the proper method is a "Menu_Point"-object which inherits from the KinectControl-class.

After recognizing a click gesture, the "source" respectively "Menu_Point"-object raises the ClickEvent like this:

```
invokeCtrl.Raise<RoutedEventArgs>("Click", new RoutedEventArgs(KinectControl.ClickEvent));
```

which calls the following method:

```
        public static void Raise<TEventArgs>(this object source, string eventName, TEventArgs eventArgs) where TEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        var list = 
            source.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | 
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | 
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.SetField | 
            BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance);
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = 
            source.GetType().GetField(eventName, BindingFlags.Public | 
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static |
            BindingFlags.GetField);

        var eventDelegate = 
            (MulticastDelegate)fieldInfo.GetValue(source);

        if (eventDelegate != null)
        {
            foreach (var handler in eventDelegate.GetInvocationList())
            {
                handler.Method.Invoke(handler.Target, new object[]{ source, eventArgs });
            }
        }
    }
```

It works fine intil the Raise-method is called and gets to this line:
`FieldInfo fieldInfo = 
                source.GetType().GetField(eventName, BindingFlags.Public | 
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static |
                BindingFlags.GetField);`
I don't know why, but the fieldInfo ist always remaining `null` which causes an exception if `eventDelegate` is trying to get access to it. Unfortunately I'm not able to find the reason why the ClickEvent is not found in this case. The member `eventName` has the value "Click" which is the name of the Event in the KinectControl-class. I also searched this site for answers (but none of the solutions helped me so far) and I read all kinds of regarding blogs like DotNetPearls.com but still I can't seem to find the mistake here.
I hope you can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Edit: added `BindingFlags.Static`; forgot that in the FieldInfo. Thanks @Michael Gunter. Still doesn't work, though.

Comment: The AddHandler() method here is likely to be the DependencyObject.AddHandler() method.  Which stores the event in an internal Dictionary in a field named "dependencyPropertyValues".  You'll have to dig that out with reflection.  This is *not* supposed to be easy.

Comment: Doesn't sound easy, indeed. Luckily, the solution of @Andreas Prechtl worked for me. The method goes through (I think) all events of all Framework elements and finds the "Click" event eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you just invoke `UIElement.RaiseEvent` - RoutedEvents don't need to have an actual EventHandler implementation - that's why they simply delegate that work to `UIElement.AddHandler`and `UIElement.RemoveHandler`.

Having said that - here's how you'll most likely find the event:

```
    public static RoutedEvent GetEvent(this UIElement source, string eventName)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventName))
            throw new ArgumentException("eventName");

        // check if the type is directly in there, otherwise you need a second pass and a more general approach
        RoutedEvent routedEvent = null;

        // this may return null...
        RoutedEvent[] events = EventManager.GetRoutedEventsForOwner(source.GetType());

        if (events != null)
            routedEvent = events.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == eventName);

        return routedEvent ?? EventManager.GetRoutedEvents().FirstOrDefault(p => p.OwnerType.IsInstanceOfType(source) && p.Name == eventName);
    }

    public static void RaiseEvent(this UIElement source, string eventName)
    {
        RoutedEvent routedEvent = GetEvent(source, eventName);

        if (routedEvent != null)
            source.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(routedEvent, source));
    }
}
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
var eventField = source.GetType().GetField(eventName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var eventDelegate = eventField.GetValue(source) as MulticastDelegate;
if (eventDelegate != null)
    eventDelegate.DynamicInvoke(new object[] { source, eventArgs });
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. Somehow eventField remained `null` just as fieldInfo. Thanks though!