# Hand Pointer in Kinect

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

Does anybody know how to use the `HandPointer` class of Kinect SDK 1.7?

I have been trying to make an object `hand` of class `HandPointer` and print a message to the console when the hand is **Gripped** without success. I am not able to create the `hand` object.

Here are the MSDN links for the [`HandPointer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.toolkit.controls.handpointer.aspx) and  [`HandPointer` members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.toolkit.controls.handpointer_members.aspx).

Here's an example code segment:

```
//First I make the HandPointer object:

HandPointer hand;

//then later I check :

if (hand.IsInGripInteraction)
  Console.WriteLine("The hand is gripped");
```

The error is that my `HandPointer` object `hand` is `null` when I run the code.
Is there any initialization which needs to be run?

Comment: Show us your code (ideally in the form of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) and tell us **how** it's failing (what it's doing and what you expect it to do).

Comment: I just posted a similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152757/kinect-sdk-1-7-mapping-joint-cursor-coordinates-to-screen-resolution/17215765#17215765

Answer (score 2):

In C#, all classes are **reference types**. A reference type variable defaults to `null`, so you will generally need to create an instance of the class with the `new` keyword and assign it:

```
List<string> names; // starts off as null

// the following line would cause a null reference exception
// names.Add("names");

names = new List<string>(); // create an instance

// now you can safely work with it
names.Add("names");

// of course, you can also initialize when you declare
List<string> names2 = new List<string>();

names2.Add("names2");
```

Based on the documentation you linked, however, the `HandPointer` class does not have any public constructors, so you can't do this. It is essentially an abstract class. In this case, it seems you need to instead create an instance of the [`KinectRegion` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.toolkit.controls.kinectregion_members.aspx) and access its [`HandPointers` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.toolkit.controls.kinectregion.handpointers.aspx).

Not being familiar at all with Kinect programming, I can't offer any advice on setting up the `KinectRegion`; you'll have to consult the [C# samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855377.aspx) included with the SDK. The two that look most applicable to you are [Controls Basics WPF-C# Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855379.aspx) and [InteractionGallery-WPF C# Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj663801.aspx).