# Using Events From A Class

Tags: events, kinect, invoke

I am trying to get a function to be called everytime an event occurs. In the KinectRegion class there is an event called HandPointerGrip: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.toolkit.controls.kinectregion.handpointergrip.aspx.

I see that it has declared the event and it seems to me that the event has already been set to be invoked(HandPointerEventArgs)? How do I attach a function to this event?

```csharp
public Menu()
{
    KinectRegion.HandPointerGripEvent+=Hand_Gripped; // why doesn't this work? :(
}    

private void Hand_Gripped(object sender, HandPointerEvnetArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("I work!"); // I wish this would work
}
```

Been working hard on this problem and here is something I think will work. Afraid to test it. Learning a lot about routed events, delegates, and events.

```csharp
namespace ...
{
    public delegate void HandPointerEventHandler(object sender, HandPointerEventArgs e);
    public partial class thePage : Page
    {
        public event HandPointerEventHandler HandGripped
        {
            add {this.AddHandler(KinectRegion.HandPointerGripEvent,value);}
            remove {this.RemoveHandler(KinectRegion.HandPointerGripEvent,vlaue);}
        }

        public thePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.HandGripped += new HandPointerEventHandler(OnHandGripped);
        }

        protected virtual void OnHandGripped(object sender, HandPointerEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hello"); //hopefully
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first block of code should work fine.  My guess is that the HandPointerGripEvent is hooked up ok, it just never fires.

How are you setting up your KinectRegion?
Are you updating the interration library each frame?

Perhaps this helps?
[Kinect SDK 1.7: Mapping Joint/Cursor Coordinates to screen Resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152757/kinect-sdk-1-7-mapping-joint-cursor-coordinates-to-screen-resolution/17215765#17215765)

Comment: I get a static readonly field cannot be assigned to for the first block of code and += operator cannot be applied to a System.Windows.RoutedEvent and metod group. I just resorted to using AddHandPointer<EventHandlers> like KinectRegion.AddHandPointerMoveHanlder(); Now i'm stuck on how to create trigger statements fo rthe mouse. For instance, when the hand is pressed I want the mouse to click at its current point (as if there was a physical click).

Answer (score 0):

```csharp
KinectRegion.AddHandPointerGripHandler(this.Button1, this.Button1_Click);
```

Here `Button1` is:

```csharp
< k:KinectTileButton x:Name="Button1" Height="150" Width="150" Content="Click"/ >
```

The namespaces:

- `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`
- `xmlns:k="http://schemas.microsoft.com/kinect/2013"`

`Button1_Click` is the method itself, for example:

```csharp
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("YOU GOT ME !!!");
}
```

If you want to add a grip handler for another interface object, you just do:

```csharp
KinectRegion.AddHandPointerGripHandler(< object name >, < method name >);
```

And s.o.